# IOS Push Notification in .net core with http v2.0

Tags: c#, ios, .net, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have created a service that includes everything very well to send ios push notification as in documentation.

I use http v2 as

```
httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(request.Payload);
httpRequest.Version = new Version(2, 0);
```

and my payload is OK.

I actually wonder about my certificate. When i send request i get this error:

```
 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__86.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsyncCore>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
   at
```

And while i configure and set my baseaddress in startup.cs, my certificates end date looks like:
[image]

Is it related with cert or not? Do you have any experience?

My service is:

```
public async Task<SendNotificationIOSResponse> SendPushNotificationIOS(SendNotificationIOSRequest request)
        {
            var response = new SendNotificationIOSResponse();
            var url = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _configuration["PushNotificationSettings:ApplePushNotificationBaseAddress"], _configuration["PushNotificationSettings:ApplePushNotificationPath"], request.DeviceToken);

            using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
            {
                httpRequest.Headers.Add("apns-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
                httpRequest.Headers.Add("apns-push-type", "alert");
                httpRequest.Headers.Add("apns-priority", "10");
                httpRequest.Headers.Add("apns-topic", _configuration["PushNotificationSettings:AppleBundleId"]);

                httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(request.Payload);
                httpRequest.Version = new Version(2, 0);

              

                using (var httpResponseMessage = await _client.SendAsync(httpRequest))
                {
                    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        response.IsSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var contentString = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var responseMessageString = httpResponseMessage.ToString();
                        response.Message = string.Format("{0}, Content:{1}", responseMessageString, contentString);
                        response.IsSuccess = false;
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanna find an answer that the error related with certificate or is it about http v.2